# Expanding div from container to the right edge of viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a centered container `div` and with this I have 2 divs one floated left and one floated right. Within the right floated I have a child `div` which I'd like to expand to the right edge of the viewport.

I've tried loads of methods from cal to vw options and just can't find a good solution to do this. I'd ideally prefer a less hacky approach because I'd like it to function fine on mobile devices (iOS etc). Here's the code I have so far:

**CODE**

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1360px;
}

.left {
  background: #0095ff;
  float: left;
  width: 32.35294%;
  height: 100px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 66.17647%;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  height: 100px;
}

.right .stretch {
  background: #ff8227;
  height: 50px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="stretch">right</div>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ecr10ago/1/

Here is an image to illustrate. It the light orange bit that i'm trying to expand out.  [image]

Comment: You want it to have the same height that the blue div?

Comment: The height is irrelevant, just the width i'm concerned about. I only made the div on the right 50px so you could see where the container div (in grey) finished,

Comment: So, you want to move it out from the .right div to overflow to the right empty space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with hiding horizontal overflow on the body, the my solution below should do the trick for you.

My making .stretch absolutely positioned, relative to it's parent .right, I was able to achieve the effect.

What I was unable to do was find a solution that would place it on the right edge of the viewport, so I used a fixed value, and hid the horizontal overflow on the body.

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1360px;
}

.left {
  background: #0095ff;
  float: left;
  width: 32.35294%;
  height: 100px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 66.17647%;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.right .stretch {
  background: #ff8227;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -2000px;
  left: 0;
}


.clear {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="stretch">right</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work James. If i pull my screen out to full width 27" the .stretch div doesn't touch the right edge of the viewport (there is a white gap).

Comment: Just change the -500px value to -2000px then

Comment: Super -600px does the job. I have a background image on the .stretch div with background-size set to cover. So -2000px was a bit of overkill and massively over sizing the bg image. Had me stumped that one. Simple solution cheers James